# In Angular 7 ng build --prod is not working

Tags: angular

1)Error TS2395: Individual declarations in merged declaration 'CCURLActionComponent' must be all exported or all local.
2) error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'CCURLActionComponent'.
3) error TS2395: Individual declarations in merged declaration 'CCURLActionComponent' must be all exported or all local.
How to slove above errors

Comment: Please format the question. Include Code Snippets so that the community members can reproduce the problem to help you

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution now its working..
change the following-

In aslaURLActionComponent

@Injectable()
export  class  aslaURLActionComponent  extends CCURLActionComponent implements OnInit {
}

And import it into  module.ts file.